# Crash on glTexImage2D when trying to display a cubemap

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am downloading an image from a URL, and storing the bitmap in the Bitmap variable bitmap. Then I do this:

```
Log.d("log", String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth())); //gives me 1536
Log.d("log", String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight())); //gives me 9216
Log.d("log", String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount())); // gives me 56623104

int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount(); 
ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(pixels);

GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
        0,
        GLES20.GL_RGB,
        bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(),
        0,
        GLES20.GL_RGB,
        GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        pixels);
```

But this leads to a crash in this the line having `glTexImage2D()`

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: what does the Logcat say? copy and paste in your Q?

Comment: When I attach the debugger, the application crashes. That is why I had to do a Log.d to see the value of the variables.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: No, I am using IntelliJ

Comment: then im not sure. You need to see the errors in the logcat as they contain more information about the crash

Comment: @Tasos Could you help with this please ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391371/rendering-an-image-texture-into-a-cubemap-in-opengl-android

Comment: bytecount / (width*height) gives 32 bits per pixel, GL_RGB is 24 bits only, you may want to consider using GL_RGBA. also you need to set the wrap and filter via gltexparameteri, so it wont appear black