# Rendering an image texture into a cubemap in openGL android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a bitmap on my device(which is a 6x1 cubemap), which I want to render on all the faces of the cube

```
 InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.photo);
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
 int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
 ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
 bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(pixels);
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;

attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;
attribute vec4 aColor;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;
  vColor = aColor;
}
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying vec4 vColor;

uniform samplerCube sTexture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = textureCube(sTexture, vec3(vTextureCoord, 1.0)) * vColor;
}
```

And here is what I am doing in my renderer in onSurfaceCreated():

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
int[] texIds = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texIds, 0);
m360PhotoTextureId = texIds[0];

GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    mTextureId);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++ ){
  pixels.position(0);
  GLES20.glTexImage2D(
      GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
      0,
      GLES20.GL_RGBA,
      1,
      1,
      0,
      GLES20.GL_RGBA,
      GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      pixels);
}

GLES20.glTexParameteri(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
        GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
        GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
        GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
        GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
```

All I see is a black screen in my texture view, when I expect to see a photo(in the pixels) being rendered on all the faces of the cube.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

I tried:
Vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
varying vec3 vTextureCoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
  vTextureCoord = aPosition.xyz;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 vTextureCoord;
uniform samplerCube sTexture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = textureCube(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
}
```

But I get the same black screen.

Comment: What color is the first pixel in the bitmap? Since that's the only pixel you're using, the result should render completely in that color. Also, did you verify that the geometry renders correctly by simply setting a constant color in the fragment shader?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, I tried setting a single color in the fragment shader. But then its hard to visualize since all the faces are of that same color. And yes, the first pixels is black. But I am just trying to set the buffer pointer to 0. Does pixels.position(0); not do what I want?I want each face to load the whole image.

Comment: From the docs, it says that "width × height texels are read from memory, starting at location data. " https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml

Comment: Yes, but you're passing 1 for both the width and height arguments.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I also tried setting 1536(the width) x 1536, but got the same result

Comment: Well, passing in the correct size would be a start. Not sure why you expect better results if you pass in a completely wrong size. 1536 might be larger than the maximum supported size. You can query the value of `MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE` to find out the maximum size.

Comment: pass the correct size and pixel format of bitmap, bind the correct texture handle on initialization and before draw; normalize vTextureCoord;

Answer (score 2):

A [cubemap texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture) is a texture who's images represent the faces of a cube. The "texture coordinate" for a cubemap texture is the *vector direction* from the center of the cube which points to the color you want to use.

You are trying to use a regular old 2D texture coordinate, with a third component probably added to silence the compiler. You must provide *directions*, not 2D coordinates. You can generate them in the vertex shader from your position. But that requires knowing what space `aPosition` is, and you didn't tell me. So I can't show you how to do that.

Regardless, the vertex shader needs to be providing a 3D direction for the texture coordinate. It should either be generated or passed from a VS input.

Note that your program may have other problems. But this is the problem that can be deduced from your code.

Comment: I updated my answer with the vs and fs I tried, but I still get the same black screen